# What's the importance of Laravel hasMany and belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship, one-to-many

According to Laravel documentation OneToOne, OneToMany and ManyToMany relationships are available.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

```
users
id - integer
name - string

roles
    id - integer
    name - string

role_user
    user_id - integer
    role_id - integer

class User extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role');
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change above many to many relationship as follows with hasMany removing the pivot table?
And what are the disadvantages of doing that? `users` and `roles` are just an example.

```
users
id - integer
role_id - integer
name - string

roles
    id - integer
    name - string

class User extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Role');
    }
}
```

Comment: First one: user can have many roles. Second one: user can only have one role. "_And what are the disadvantages of doing that?_" What are the advantages?

Comment: @kerbh0lz User can have many roles with composite key (id + role_id) in 'User' table.

Comment: Not with the second approach. A user with an id of `1` can only have _one_ role (in `users` table) given that `id` is an auto-incrementing primary key (there cannot be another user with an id of `1`)